# Missing parent column in insertion when it saves a parent-child association in Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Do you know because a parent field could not be part of the insert statement even though there is parent-association defined in the model classes?

Basically, i want to save the creator logged into the application in a document submission table when it save its questions. By the way, questions are saved properly. Here is my [database model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IFfy.png)

Also, below is the classes I created and modified

**JSON which is sent from the browser**

```
Parameters: {"submission"=>{"responses_attributes"=>{"0"=> {"question_id"=>"71", "answer"=>"Answer 1-10"}, 
                        "1"=>{"question_id"=>"72", "answer"=>"Answer 1-10"}}}, "document_id"=>"1"}
```

**Document submissions controller**

```
class DocumentSubmissionsController < ApplicationController

  def index

    @document = Document.find_by_slug(params[:document_id])
    @submissions = @document.submissions.includes(:responses)

  end

  def create

   document = Document.find_by_slug(params[:document_id])

   if document.submissions.create(submission_params)
     render json: document, status: 200
   else
     render status: 400
   end

  end

  private

   def submission_params

     params.require(:submission).permit(
       submission: [admin_id: 1],
       responses_attributes: [
         :question,
         :answer_value
       ]
     )
   end
end
```

**Submission and response model classes**

```
class Submission < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Associations
   belongs_to :document, inverse_of: :submissions
   has_many :responses, class_name: "SubmissionResponse", inverse_of:    :submission, dependent: :destroy

   belongs_to :creator

  # Nested Attributes

   accepts_nested_attributes_for :responses

end

class Creator < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :submissions

end
```

**Insert statement got from Rails track**

(0.4ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (4.3ms)  INSERT INTO "document_submissions" ("document_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"
  [["document_id", 1], ["created_at", "2016-06-12 21:07:57.481249"], ["updated_at", "2016-06-12 21:07:57.481249"]]
    ... response inserts.... 
(0.9ms)  COMMIT

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just do

```
if document.submissions.create(submission_params) && document.update_attributes(creator_id: current_user.id)
     render json: document, status: 200
   else
     render status: 400
   end
```